# CSS equal columns

Tags: css, html

How hard is it to achieve two divs be the same height?

I want this header (image & menu) to be responsive: http://test.kinoume.gr/
I don't want to specify a height in header, but rather take the images height.

HTML

```
   <header class="row-fluid">
  <div id="headerimage" class="span3">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://test.kinoume.gr/img/kinoume-logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
  </div>

  <div id="menu" class="span9">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
img {max-width: 100%;}
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; padding:0;margin:0;}

a:link, a:visited {color:#9e8f7a;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
html {margin: 0;padding: 0;height:100%;}
body {background: #fff;margin: 0;max-width:1600px;height:100%;position:relative;padding:0}

header {border-bottom:7px solid #9e8f7a;background-color:#fff;}
nav ul {overflow: hidden;list-style-type: none;margin:0;}
nav ul li {float:left;display:inline-block;position: relative;margin:0 3% 0 0;padding-top:8px;}
nav ul li.active {border-top:8px #40ccd6 solid;}
nav ul li a {position: absolute; top:45%;font-size:1.3rem;}
li.active a {top:41%;}
```

...and http://jsfiddle.net/gong_planet/kzngh/1/

Comment: I never got the "i want" approach, it reminds me too much of clients rather than a community member in need of help.

Comment: I want this header (image & menu) to be responsive means?

Comment: _“How hard is it to achieve two divs be the same height?”_ – how hard is it to do your own research on a topic that has been discussed this broadly all over then net for at least five years?

Comment: first of all "I want" doesn't mean I demand. I never demand not even when I am a client. Secondly of course I did a research... but couldn't find something even close to what I want to do.

Comment: Maybe you want to use a framework like Foundation or Bootstrap which provide great tools to create a top navbar:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html &
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Comment: The height of the divs is not the issue. The issue is that everything in the `ul`is floating and absolute, so the `ul` collapses. Give it a `min-height` and you're alright.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PfVfx/)**

In your CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex; /* This is where the magic happens */
}
```

Flexbox will, by default, stretch the columns to be of equal height.